# hard disk space lost when I installed ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

My system has a 320GB hard disk and has windows 7 installed.
Then I installed Ubuntu 12.10 (now upgraded to 13.10) which uses 15GB. Now only 246GB(C:\ drive 186GB, F:\ drive 30GB, E:\ drive 30) is seen. I lost almost 70GB of space. Where did it go?

This was the output for the command  `sudo fdisk -l`; mount

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x31a7d29a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    28338175    14168064   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2   *    28338176    28542975      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        28542976   420340399   195898712    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       420343806   625141759   102398977    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       420343808   485272805    32464499    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       549472256   611057663    30792704    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda7       617056256   625141759     4042752   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda8       611059712   613296127     1118208   83  Linux
/dev/sda9       613298176   617039871     1870848   83  Linux
/dev/sda10      485273600   549470207    32098304   83  Linux
```

Partition table entries are not in disk order

```
$ mount
/dev/sda10 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=sajeena)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information here to determine a solution to your situation. From what I can see, you have a lot of small partitions that I can't determine the function of. Can you provide the following to help diagnose?

1. contents of `/etc/fstab` - this will tell us where your OS, swap, and maybe data partitions are.
2. `ls -l /dev/disk/by-label` - If there are any user- or system-configured labels on the partitions that might hint as to their purpose this will show them.
3. Mount each partition (except for `/dev/sda10`) under /mnt and show us the contents.

.

```
for n in 1 2 3 5 6 8 9
do 
  sudo mkdir -p /mnt/sda$n
  sudo mount /dev/sda$n /mnt/sda$n && tree -d -L 2 /mnt/sda$n
done
```

The above script makes the directories `/mnt/sda1` through `/mnt/sda9` and then mounts each of the partitions on to those directories. If the mount succeeds, it runs `tree` to shows the directory tree (out to two levels) of the directories on those partitions. Hopefully this will give us some insight as to what is on each partition. Partitions 4 and 7 are not included because 4 is an extended partition shell (which just contains 5-10) and 7 is a swap partition so the data is not in a mountable filesystem.

Here are my guesses:

```
Device      Size (GB)  Function 
/dev/sda1    13.51     Windows Recovery Partition (OEM)
/dev/sda2     0.10     Windows System Partition (WinVista/7/8 Boot Partition)
/dev/sda3   186.82     Windows OS
/dev/sda4   ------     Contains /dev/sda5 -> /dev/sda9
/dev/sda5    30.96     Data Partition?
/dev/sda10   30.61     Root filesystem for Ubuntu
/dev/sda6    29.37     Data Partition?
/dev/sda8     1.07     ?
/dev/sda9     1.78     ?
/dev/sda7     3.86     Linux Swap
```